# Showing/Hiding button in custom cell on demand not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to show a button on certain cells in my tableview depending on type of image showing in that cell

soo i have two NSMutableArray's one holding the thumbnail image URL's and the other NSMutableArray holding the type of the url if it was image or video

the problem is the button doesn't show on all the video type cells

here is my code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TVCustomCell";

TVCustom *cell = (TVCustom *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TVCustom" owner:self options:nil];
    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[TVCustom class]]) {
            cell = (TVCustom *) currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    NSString *imgURL = [arrayImagesURL objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imgURL];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        cell.thumbImg.image = image;
    });
});

NSString *MediaType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrayType objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

if ([MediaType isEqualToString:@"video"]) {
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(120, 319, 50, 30);
    [button setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.tag = indexPath.row;
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(PlayBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
}

return cell;
}
```

i don't know what i'm doing wrong, any idea ?

Comment: once check  button.frame = CGRectMake(120, 319, 50, 30); frame of this button y coordinate starts from 319 once check it.

Comment: @Sunny Yes, my custom cell Height is 350 and i the button is on the bottom of the cell, its not outside the cell frame

Comment: Why do you allocate the button every time, even you have your own custom cell `TVCustom`. Add the button on TVCustom and hide or show according to the MediaType.

Comment: once check with breakpoints weather that block excuted or not?

Comment: @trick14 did that already and with the same problem

Comment: @Sunny it is, even if not what should fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see different problems here.

## First

Your code creates new buttons every time the user scrolls in the tableView. This is because you use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` which is great and returns existing cells instead of creating new ones.

But then you add a new button on cells which already exist (and may or may not have a button)

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:button];
```

I suggest you add the button in your `TVCustom` class:

In the TVCustom.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *viedoButton;
```

In TVCustom.m

```
- (UIButton *)videoButton
{
    if (!_videoButton) {
        _videoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        _videoButton.frame = CGRectMake(120, 319, 50, 30);
        [_videoButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_videoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(PlayBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        _videoButton.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
        [self.contentView _videoButton];
    }
    return _videoButton;
}
```

Then in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` you only do :

```
if ([MediaType isEqualToString:@"video"]) {
    cell.videoButton.hidden = NO;
} else {
    cell.videoButton.hidden = YES;
}
```

This way every cell will have only one button and it will be visible only when you need it but not re-allocated every time. But `PlayBtnClicked` will have to be in your `TVCustom` class and **call your viewController through a delegate**.

## Second

You should not handle the loading of your image in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Encapsulate it your `TVCustom` class:

In TVCustom.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *imgURL;
```

In TVCustom.m

```
- (void)setImgURL:(NSString *)imgURL
{
    _imgURL = imgURL;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

         NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imgURL];
         NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
             self.thumbImg.image = image;
         });
    });
 }
```

Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it will look like :

```
cell.imgURL = [arrayImagesURL objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

## Third

I do not know if you have any particular reason for this:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TVCustom" owner:self options:nil];
    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[TVCustom class]]) {
            cell = (TVCustom *) currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But a good way to do this is in your viewController's `viewDidLoad` (or other method):

```
NSString *identifier = @"TVCustomCell";
NSString *nibName = @"TVCustom";
UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithName:nibName];
[self.tableView registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:identifier];
```

Your final code should look like :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TVCustomCell";

    TVCustom *cell = (TVCustom *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.imgURL = [arrayImagesURL objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([MediaType isEqualToString:@"video"]) {
        cell.videoButton.hidden = NO;
    } else {
        cell.videoButton.hidden = YES;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: tried to do what you said, regarding the button, i get a lot of errors  of your code, its not right, can you please check it ?, thank you

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change the button variable name to `videoButton`. You may have an `Undeclared selector PlayBtnClicked` warning if you forgot to add this method in your cell class.

Comment: the code you provide is still not working after your update, error *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<TVCustom 0x8c56450> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key viedoButton.' ,, can you please run the code and check it ?

Comment: It worked, thanks man, **UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithName:nibName];** should be **UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];** , and the other thing was me adding the button on the nib and connecting it with files owner, that was wrong, when i removed it it worked

Comment: Nice, sorry I could not use XCode to test right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57484/discussion-between-alfarsi-and-tanguy).

Comment: @Tanguy ,Hello dear. I'v a query. In my tableview ,I have 5 cells each with image. How would i check that image at each cell is hidden or not ?

Comment: Hey ! I am sorry I need more context. Open a you question with more details and ping me the link